# Converting javascript onclick event to react

Tags: javascript, react-native

So previously I had very simple html code that did not use any framework.

Part of this method was returning html and generate button with onclick functionality.

```
return "<button onclick=\"deleteBrochure('" +
albumName +
"','" +
photoKey +
"')\">",
"DELETE",
"</button>"
```

I know that in react I have to translate onclick to onClick and add {} for method so it would look something like that:

```
return "<button onClick=\"{() => this.deleteBrochure('" +
        albumName +
        "','" +
        photoKey +
        "')}\">",
        "DELETE",
        "</button>"
```

I am not getting any browser errors, but deleteBrochure is never triggered.
Is there more to it than just changing syntax?

Just started working on react today, so apologies if this question is too easy for some people.

Comment: That's a string, not JSX. It really isn't clear what this has to do with React.

Comment: Me too not an expert but seems that you are passing a string to onClick and not a function or I'm wrong? I would remove `"` before and after bracket.

Comment: You are wrapping your jsx element of button in " " or string. That's not how it works. remove the "" from button as well as after onClick=

Comment: i guess docs for handling events is clearly and understand-able at web :)